# $wpdb error (Call to a member function insert() on a non-object)

Tags: database, wpdb

I have very few knowledge on oo php and databases, and I am simply trying to insert data in my wp_pagesvisites table but I am having some trouble with this error message.

This is my script:

```
$wpdb->insert(
    'wp_pagesvisites',
    array(
        'Adresse_IP' => $ip,
        'Post_ID' => $id,
        'Timestamp' => $time
    )
);
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$wpdb` is a global variable. You have to take it into your function’s scope first …

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert();
```

… or access it per `$GLOBALS` …

```
$GLOBALS['wpdb']->insert();
```

And I would use always lowercase keys; this is just a useful convention.

Comment: I did same but still getting the same issue